# How to estimate the mobility of atoms implanted in the interstitials and/or vacancies of a crystal?

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, atoms, crystals

I would like to compare the likelihood for implanted helium atoms to move from interstitials/vacancies of a crystal versus neon atoms. I read in the literature that He atoms located in interstitials/vacancies of a metal are very mobile due to their "small size" and can thus agglomerate into bigger structures (dislocation loops) if many He atoms are in the same vicinity, resulting in the creation of subsurface He bubbles. This effect is not observed with Ne atoms, so I guess that the implanted Ne atoms are not that mobile, maybe because they are "bigger".

Would you say that this is true, and if yes how could I compare the mobility (and size) of He atoms vs. Ne atoms in a crystal, at least qualitatively and maybe even quantitatively?

Thank you very much in advance.

Julien.

**Edit**: As additional information, I just looked up what atomic radii come up for those elements, are here are the results:

Van der Waals radius: $r_\text{He}= 140$ pm, $r_\text{Ne} = 154$ pm

Ionic radius (calculated): $r_\text{He}= 31$ pm, $r_\text{Ne} = 38$ pm

Covalent radius: $r_\text{He}= 28$ pm, $r_\text{Ne} = 58$ pm

Only the covalent radius seems significantly different. Note that the values for the ionic radius have not been measured but calculated.